# How do I cycle through this dictionary?

Tags: nsdictionary, paypal-adaptive-payments

This is the output of an NSDictionary:

```
{
    client =     {
        environment = mock;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "1.0.3";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    payment =     {
        amount = "39.95";
        "currency_code" = USD;
        "short_description" = "Awesome saws";
    };
    "proof_of_payment" =     {
        "adaptive_payment" =         {
            "app_id" = "APP-1245783590";
            "pay_key" = "AP-70M62356425642W";
            "payment_exec_status" = COMPLETED;
            timestamp = "2012-03-03T15:53:55Z";
        };
    };
```

Its from Paypal Adaptive Payments.  I ended up doing this:

```
- (void)verifyCompletedPayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {

    NSDictionary *pOPDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:completedPayment.confirmation];
    NSLog(@"pOPDictionary: %@",pOPDictionary);

    NSDictionary *subDictionary = [pOPDictionary objectForKey:@"proof_of_payment"];
    NSDictionary *sub2Dictionary = [subDictionary objectForKey:@"adaptive_payment"];
    NSString *proofString = [sub2Dictionary objectForKey:@"payment_exec_status"];

    if ([proofString isEqualToString:@"COMPLETED"]) {
        NSLog(@"Payment Completed Successfully");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Payment Error");
    }

    NSData *confirmation = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:completedPayment.confirmation options:0 error:nil];

}
```

Is there a more efficient way to get that key from the dictionary of dictionary of dictionaries?  I only really need that key.  So i didnt think I should cycle or loop thru the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two 2 different possibilities how you can simplify the code. You can use the "Modern Objective-C subscripting syntax" (see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html for more information):

```
NSDictionary *pOPDictionary = completedPayment.confirmation;
NSString *proofString = pOPDictionary[@"proof_of_payment"][@"proof_of_payment"][@"payment_exec_status"];
```

Or Key-Value Coding:

```
NSDictionary *pOPDictionary = completedPayment.confirmation;
NSString *proofString = [pOPDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"proof_of_payment.proof_of_payment.payment_exec_status"];
```

I don't think that there is an advantage of one over the other, it is just a matter of
taste which one you choose.